# Mirror values from textarea to append

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsbin.com/renabuvu/1/edit

What I'm doing is I type a CSS selector, change its values and as it's values change it applies to the page's html and is applied in real time. (This part works without a problem).

However my problem is when I append the already added values. My newly appended/cloned textarea ends up blank.

How can I solve this problem?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addvalz").on('click', function() {
    // Refresh render before add
    $("#testcode").val($(".inputval").val() +" {"+ ( $(".pad").val() === "" ? "" : "\n  padding: " + $(".pad").val() + ";" ) + ( $(".bg").val() === "" ? "" : "\n  background-color: " + $(".bg").val() + ";" ) + ( $(".boxshadow").val() === "" ? "" : "\n  box-shadow: " + $(".boxshadow").val() + ";" ) +"\n}");
    
    // Adds value
    $(".val-nester").append($("<div class='holddezvalz'>")
     .append("<button class='deldizval'>x</button>")
     .append("<button class='grabdezvalz'>"+ $(".inputval").val() +"</button>").append($("#asc #testcode:first-of-type").clone()).append($(".valz2add .inputval:first-of-type").clone()).append($(".cssvalz .pad:first-of-type").clone()).append($(".cssvalz .bg:first-of-type").clone()).append($(".cssvalz .boxshadow:first-of-type").clone())
);
    $("#apply-test-code").html("<style type='text/css'>"+ $("#testcode").val() +"</style>");

    // Grabs selector value
    $(".grabdezvalz").on('click', function() {
      $(".valz2add .inputval:first-of-type").val($(this).next().next().val());
      $(".cssvalz .pad:first-of-type").val($(this).next().next().next().val());
      $(".cssvalz .bg:first-of-type").val($(this).next().next().next().next().val());
      $(".cssvalz .boxshadow:first-of-type").val($(this).next().next().next().next().next().val());
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I did post a fiddle. It's the first link in the post.

Comment: @mikethedj4 You mean when you change values in white textarea, they are not reflected?

Comment: My mistake. Unfortunately, the fiddle is unclear. There is too much going on to be able to quickly zero in on the problem code.

Comment: @j809 No I can reflect the values fine, but I'm trying to append reflected values in with the textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/renabuvu/2/edit

Because the values are being mirrored to the textarea and not applied, clone will only apply the textarea to it's set values not what's being mirrored/reflected upon it.

I had to add it as a string and then it worked perfectly.

```
$(".val-nester").append($("<div class='holddezvalz'>")
                .append("<button class='deldizval'>x</button>")
                .append("<button class='grabdezvalz'>"+ $(".inputval").val() +"</button>")
                .append("<textarea>"+ $("#asc #testcode:first-of-type").val() +"</textarea>")
                .append($(".valz2add .inputval:first-of-type").clone())
                .append($(".cssvalz .pad:first-of-type").clone())
                .append($(".cssvalz .bg:first-of-type").clone())
                .append($(".cssvalz .boxshadow:first-of-type").clone())
);
```